# List all the male Voices for tts -iOS

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

```
 let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
```

This will return all the voices present in the mobile. 
I want to list all the male and female voices separately. 
and also can we ask the user to download specific voice . ?

Comment: You can get name, language and identifier.  What do you mean download a voice?

Comment: I know we can get names but in my previous version used "Aaron" - for selecting male voice and perform TTS. it got deleted when iOS 12 rolled out.  Now it's not showing "Aaron" in listed voice. 
so I want the user to download voice   "Aaron" for TTS.

Comment: If it's not in the list then it's not available for the users to download in core iOS. Best suggestion is to open a support ticket in your developer account to get further help from Apple.